# Read information from Outlook and move email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found this VBA macro to read information inside emails that works fine, I need to modify the macro to move items in another folder after reading information:

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("test")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        OutlookMail.UnRead = False
        i = i + 1
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I try to modify the macro as below, now it's working but It move not all the emails, only half every script running:

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim MoveToFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("test")
Set MoveToFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("test_fatto")

i = 0

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        OutlookMail.UnRead = False
        OutlookMail.Move MoveToFolder
        i = i + 1
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set MoveToFolder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you modify the macro you found to achieve what you want? What didn't work and you need help with? Please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `foreach` loop you may try to use the `while` or `do`/`while` loops:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
```

so, instead, you may use the following:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim items as Outlook.Items

Set items = Folder.Items
Set mail as Object

While items.Count > 0
    Debug.Print(index.ToString & " ")
    index += 1

    Set mail = items.GetLast()
End While
```

Also please remember that a folder may contain different types of items. So, you need to check out the item type before casting it to a particular class or accessing specific properties available not in all items types.